React: How do I specify the order of useState setter?
I am trying to get a list of documents from their ids:
const [postReplies, setPostReplies] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        setPostReplies([]);
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            fetch(document_i)
            .then((data) => {
                setPostReplies((postReplies) => [...postReplies, data])
            })
        }
    }
       
}, []);

I want the array to be sorted in the order that I sent the request, and the react state to be reset each time.

What do you want to happen if, say, only request #3 has finished so far. Do you want the state to contain an array of [undefined, undefined, someData, undefined]? Or should it wait until all 4 have been loaded, and only then set the state?

@NicholasTower Either is fine, I am rendering these items so it's fine if it shows undefined for a split second

If you want the array to fill in piece by piece as each request finishes, then use i to dictate where to insert the data. Be aware that this means that on some renders the array will contain undefined values:
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  fetch(document_i)
    .then(data) => {
       setPostReplies(prev => {
         const next = [...prev];
         next[i] = data;
         return next;
       });
    });
}

If you want to wait until all the data is loaded: create an array of promises, combine them using Promise.all, and wait for that promise to finish.
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  promises.push(fetch(document_i));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(replies => {
  setPostReplies(replies);
});

